# Switching to windows from the dock causes other windows to open

Tags: macos, dock

Occasionally when clicking on an open application in the dock (e.g. Finder.app) another window will open with it, the best example I can give is that when I am in Photoshop and need to get something from Finder I click on Finder and Firefox (which was already open) shows it window. This is very inconvenient and I cannot find a correlation between when this happens and when it doesn't.

**EDIT:**

As it turns out this can also happen when using `Cmd + Tab`.

Comment: Is Finder already open on a different screen and it just didn't switch to that screen or do you mean Firefox just pops up instead?  Also, does this happen with both the mouse and trackpad?

Comment: I generally don't use multiple screens/desktops. When I try to open a finder window (there might already be one open) (possibly other applications but I've only been noticing Finder causing this) sometimes another application will also show it's window (most often I've noticed (could be wrong) it is Mozilla Firefox).

Comment: Mouse and trackpad?

Comment: Doesn't seem to seem to matter whether I use a mouse or trackpad.